# Is my SSD dying or still brand new? And how do I interpret 'smartctl' output?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd

I have a Kingston 480Gb SSD, its 3 years old now and its count of reallocation events has been steadily increasing since I have purchased it and now it's at 17. I have no idea of how many reallocations are there before it runs out of spare blocks.

`smartctl` says it has 4% of lifetime left, but I have only written about 5TB of data to it, and the manufacturer claims the 480Gb version can handle up to 160TB of lifetime writes.

So basically sounds like it's either still brand new or close to death and I don't know which it is.

[Kingston A400 SSD datasheet](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/SA400S37_en.pdf)

I already have a spare SSD to back up my data, but I wonder if I should wait for this one to die before cloning it. If I understand correctly, when SSDs die they become read-only instead of unreadable, so the risk of data loss low, or at least I hope so.

here's the result from `smartctl`.

```python
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.19.0-35-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Phison Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37480G
Serial Number:    50026B76839B7AEE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 6839b7aee
Firmware Version: SBFKB1E1
User Capacity:    480.103.981.056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar  5 17:56:13 2023 -03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x05) Offline data collection activity
                                        was aborted by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (65535) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  30) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   000   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18350
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       366
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       143
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       98
167 Write_Protect_Mode      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 SATA_Phy_Error_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Bad_Block_Rate          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       31
170 Bad_Blk_Ct_Erl/Lat      0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       0/15
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 MaxAvgErase_Ct          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       46 (Average 39)
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
192 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       309
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   061   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 23/48)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17
199 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 CRC_Error_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   004   004   000    Old_age   Offline      -       96
233 Flash_Writes_GiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10513
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5528
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4146
244 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39
245 Max_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       46
246 Total_Erase_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       596384

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       144         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        47         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        47         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               00%         0         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: Looks like you may have some write amplification. Are your partitions properly aligned? // You'll have to take the SSDs value for granted. This isn't something `smartctl` calculated, but something the drive reported.

Comment: I have a single partition.

I'm confused because the raw value of SSD_Life_Left is 96, and it stated at 100 when I bought it and but gsmartcontrol tooltip states that the normed value that should be taken into account and it start at 100 and linearly decreases.

Lifetime_Writes_GiB is at 5528 which is more what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

> I already have a spare SSD to back up my data, but I wonder if I should wait for this one to die before cloning it. If I understand correctly, when SSDs die they become read-only instead of unreadable, so the risk of data loss low, or at least I hope so.

## SSD - end of life behaviour

You are wrong with your assumption about SSD behaviour. The German computer journal c't once tested SSD behaviour by permanently writing test data on them. It turned out that some of them - typically the more expensive brand ones - behaved like you expect (read operations still possible) it whereas the others died (no read or write operations possible).

An SSD that allows read only access is broken but not dead.

## hard shutdowns using the power buttons

309 Unsafe shutdowns suggest that you are mishandling your SSD.

## misaligned partitions on SSD

With regards to the comment of Daniel B., 5528 GiB write operations of the operating system caused 10513 GiB write operations on flash. This overhead can be caused by misaligned partitions.

To verify this use Testdisk, run quick searck and use the appearing backup function to create the file labeled "backup.log". Post this file.

## wear analysis

If you divide both figures (5,5 and 10,5) by 160 TiB (rated write capacity) you have plenty of margin left before the drive will have used up its writing capabilities.

Looking at the `SSD life left` attribute you notice that both figures add up to 100. I would have expected a normalized value
of 96 instead of 4 given the amount of data written.
It appears to me as a firmware bug.

## conclusion

Run the backup and watch the SMART attributs how they change over time.

Answer (score 1):

> smartctl says it has 4% of lifetime left

That's not how interpret this:

[image]

IMO it suggests 96% life time remaining as we see a raw value of 96. IOW, smartctl is wrong.

> .. reallocation events has been steadily increasing since I have
> purchased it and it's now at 17, I have no idea of how many
> reallocations before it runs out of spare blocks.

RAW value of Attribute 169 is percentage used (31). If we know 17 were reallocated and this equals 31% then there should 37 remaining spare blocks?

[image]

> when SSDs die they become read-only instead of unreadable, so the risk
> of data loss low, or at least I hope so.

I think this depends. It's not a general rule, it's a firmware 'decision' and it is one it will never be able to make in case of some catastrophic sudden failure. IOW SSD's die, while not allowing you to save the data, so it's not something I'd rely on.

I once watched an interesting Intel video about SSD's and the main difference between consumer and enterprise grade SSD's can be largely in firmware policies rather than different hardware. Policy is more strict where it concerns enterprise grade models, so fewer errors and anomalies are accepted by the firmware and so the firmware may decide to 'brick' the SSD (words of the Intel engineer) where consumer model continues functioning.

EDIT: Found the video. It's on different topic (silent errors) but is illustrates my point about these sort of things being firmware policies: amount of errors you're willing to take and different policies with regards to consumer vs. enterprise models. He discusses some of this around the 22:00 mark. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqzv2YXMFRs